# definition of my function in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to create a small tool using wxPython. Basically, I want my code to import data from a csv file and the print the name and occupation of an individual. Anyways, I'm getting an error when using find_names function inside of a search_ppl definition. The error says NameError: global name 'find_names' is not defined. I don't understand how to fix it. If I make the function find_names global the code doesn't work either. I already wrote a working code for this in python where the results are written to the terminal window. But wxPython is still new to me and I don't quite understand it yet...Thanks for your help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
import csv
from wxPython.wx import *

info = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
            "Search", pos=(920,730), size=(350,250) )

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.control = wxTextCtrl(panel, 1, style=wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER 
                        , pos=(130,180), size=(200,28))

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel
                        , style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                        , size=(350,170))

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Name", width = 120)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Occupation", width = 220)

        index = 0
        for row in info:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, row[4])

            if index % 2:
                self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, "white")
            else:
                self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, "yellow")
            index += 1

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Search", pos=(20,180))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.search_ppl)

        key_index = 4
        results = []

    def search_ppl(self, event):
                employee_name = self.control.GetValue()
        find_names(key_index, results, info, employee_name)
        print results

    def find_names(key_index, results, info, employee_name):
        for row in info: #search each row in data.csv               
                    if employee_name in row[key_index]: #name is in file                    results.append(row[1]) #add element to the list
        return results, info




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
find_names(key_index, results, info, employee_name)
```

to

```
results, info = self.find_names(key_index, results, info, employee_name)
```

Because you are calling a class method you need to use self. before the method name

You also need to set values for key_index, results & info before calling find_names

Comment: Thanks Yoriz, this made some progress. However, I still get an error. What does your last line mean? Do I need to make key_index, results and info global? My info is already a global. When I make key_index and results global I get an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment". I don't understand this. If I declare a variable as global shouldn't the code see these values? Or do I need to somehow pass them to class MyFrame?